# How to prefill tag name on GitHub new release page?

Tags: github, release

I want to be able to make an HTTP link that prefills the tag name, target branch and release title on GitHub's new Release page: https://github.com/qwertzguy/git-quick/releases/new
*Note: link won't work since you need permissions to see this page, try it on one of your repos to see how the page looks like*

Similar to how you can prefill the title and body for a new issue:
https://github.com/qwertzguy/git-quick/issues/new?title=foo&body=bar

My goal is to have a script that can open the page with the correct prefilled info so the developer can check the info and submit. I can't use the GitHub APIs as that would require devs to setup their GitHub credentials during dev environment setup.

Comment: So I just found out you can fill in the tag name using ?tag=v1.0.0
But couldn't fill any of the other fields :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just can’t. From the source of the new issue page you get
these relevant attributes:

```css
name="issue[title]" -> title
name="issue[body]" -> body
```

The from new release page you get these:

```css
name="release[tag_name]" -> tag_name
name="release[name]" -> name
name="release[body]" -> body
```

but they do not work at all:

https://github.com/svnpenn/bm/releases/new?tag_name=alfa&name=bravo&body=charlie

Comment: Setting a parameter named `tag` seems to work.  I think your answer might be wrong, as there _may_ be options that it works for (but I'll have to experiment)